In Psalm 13, what takes "take counsel in my soul" mean?
I've personally appreciated Psalm 13's expressions of emotional trouble during a difficult time, and its usefulness for prayer.
For quite a few years, I've wondered what the phrase in verse 2, really means:

2 How long shall I take counsel in my soul,...

Naturally, I've looked at the individual meanings of the words in Strongs. And I've looked at alternative translations. Examples include,

How long must I wrestle with my thoughts ...(NIV)
How long must I bear pain in my soul,... (NRS)
How long will I be left to my own wits,... (CEB)

These all seem like perfectly reasonable translations, in terms of the distress that David seems to be conveying. However, they all seem to be based on inference, rather than faithful to the original text. That is why it seems that the NKJV, or NASB have just stuck with "take counsel in my soul" to translate ʿēṣôṯ 'āšîṯ 'ānâ ʿaḏ bilḇāḇî yāḡôn bᵊnap̄šî
I see that "counsel" H6098 can also be translated as "plans" or "decisions", so maybe it does have something to do with wrestling with one's thoughts or decisions, as the NIV seems to suggest?

Hebrew is not a language I know; but, I can share something from a book I have on my shelf.  This is from the “A Translators Handbook on The Book of Psalms” published by UBS.  So, some of these observations might be helpful.

Bear pain: according to the RSV footnote this translates the Syriac (see also NAB); the Hebrew text means “hold counsels.”  But
according to some scholars the Hebrew text can be translated “How long
shall I continue devising plans (in my mind)?”  That is, the psalmist
in vain tries to think of ways to improve the situation.  So NJB “How
long must I nurse rebellion in my soul?” taking the word to have the
same meaning here that it has in 106.43b (so K-B, Holladay).  Some
scholars hold that the Hebrew word itself can mean pain, anguish (see
references in Anderson); so TEV, NEB, SPCL; NJV “cares”; BJ “grief”;
TOB “worry”; Dahood “doubts.”

It then mentions that ‘soul’ (nefesh) is parallel to ‘heart’ in the next line.  So, there appears to be Hebrew parallelism going on here.
Obviously, you're not the only one to wrestle with this text.
Personally, the idea of a wrestling that has elements of rebellion in it seems to fit the overall message of the Psalm.  David seems deeply concerned--at the beginning of the Psalm--that a lack of confidence in God will result in his enemies winning the day.  I think the fact that there's no mention of a sin is relevant to the interpretation.  God is hiding his face and this creates a wrestling within the mind of David.  Without a specific sin, the wrestling is one of faith.  And faithlessness is rebellious in its nature.  And so, the end of the Psalm, in a contrastive parallelism, is David restating his faith and confidence in God. Verse 5 is probably parallel to verse 1.
We experience a feeling of “failing God”, a sense of rebellion in our identity, when our faith is weak.  David turns the corner by the end of the Psalm and chooses to trust.

Thank you @Mike Sangrey. I was particularly interested by "But according to some scholars the Hebrew text can be translated “How long shall I continue devising plans (in my mind)?”"
That would affirm what I was concluding, that the word "counsel" could also be translated as "plans".
It would make sense to me, if David was expressing to God how, in the absence of God, he was left with anxious thoughts and speculations racing through his mind.

Here is my attempt to translate the Hebrew of Ps 13:2 very literally:

How long shall I take counsel daily in my soul, sorrow in my heart;
How long will my enemy be exalting over me

The "tricky" part here is the "take counsel in my soul".  The trick to understanding this quintessential Hebrew idiom for simple worry, is to understand

the Hebrew parallelism
the use of the Hebrew "nephesh" = "soul".

Parallelism
Note the rather obvious parallelism in the first half of the verse:

take counsel in my soul
sorrow in my heart

this is synthetic parallelism - saying the same thing in different words.  That is, the meaning of one is amplified and explained by the other.
נֶפֶשׁ = "Soul"
Here is a list of the ways that the word נֶפֶשׁ (nephesh) is translated in the NASB OT:

anyone* (1), appetite (7), being (1), beings (3), body (1), breath
(1), corpse (2), creature (6), creatures (3), dead (1), dead person
(2), deadly (1), death (1), defenseless* (1), desire (12), desire*
(2), discontented* (1), endure* (1), feelings (1), fierce* (2),
greedy* (1), heart (5), heart's (2), herself (12), Himself (4),
himself (19), human (1), human being (1), hunger (1), life (146), lifeblood* (2), lives (34), living creature (1), longing*
(1), man (4), man's (1), men* (2), mind (2), Myself (3), myself (2),
number (1), ones (1), others (1), ourselves (3), own (1), passion*
(1), people (2), people* (1), perfume* (1), person (68), person* (1),
persons (19), slave (1), some (1), soul (238), soul's (1), souls
(12), strength (1), themselves (6), thirst (1), throat (2), will (1),
wish (1), wishes (1), yourself (11), yourselves (13).

Note that nephesh often mean the whole person, even when it is a dead person.  Thus, the word often means the inner person. BDB defines it as: "*soul, living being, life, self, person, desire, appetite, emotion, and passion *".
Thus, David is attempting to say (in the absence of Hebrew abstract nouns) that he is worried, perplexed and concerned about the exultation of God's enemies over him.  This explains the somewhat interpretive translation of others such as:

NIV: wrestle with my thoughts
NLT: struggle with anguish in my soul
HCSB: store up anxious concerns within me
CEV: confused and miserable
etc


Thank you @Dottard. I've never known to look for parallelism in the Scriptures. I've never had a term for it, but I've certainly noticed it in the book of Proverbs, if not the Psalms.
So, I think what you're saying is that "take counsel in my soul" is going to have a similar meaning to "having sorrow in my heart"?
